# Reorganise 2x36 dataframe to a 6x6 dataframe. Dice throw visualisation

Tags: r, layout, dataframe, probability, dice

I've created a data-frame of all the possible outcomes from a dice throw as 2x36 dataframe.

```
    d1  d2
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   4   1
5   5   1
6   6   1
7   1   2
8   2   2
9   3   2
10  4   2
11  5   2
12  6   2
13  1   3
14  2   3
15  3   3
16  4   3
17  5   3
18  6   3
19  1   4
20  2   4
21  3   4
22  4   4
23  5   4
24  6   4
25  1   5
26  2   5
27  3   5
28  4   5
29  5   5
30  6   5
31  1   6
32  2   6
33  3   6
34  4   6
35  5   6
36  6   6
```

To make this visually more pleasing I want to re-organise it as a 6x6 table.

```
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6] 
[1,] "1 1" "1 2" "1 3" "1 4" "1 5" "1 6"
[2,] "2 1" "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5" "2 6"
[3,] "3 1" "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5" "3 6"
[4,] "4 1" "4 2" "4 3" "4 4" "4 5" "4 6"
[5,] "5 1" "5 2" "5 3" "5 4" "5 5" "5 6"
[6,] "6 1" "6 2" "6 3" "6 4" "6 5" "6 6"
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: If you show the input data and expected output, it would be easier.

Comment: Hi Akrun, unfortunately I can't seem to get the format the tables properly. But this is what i'm trying to create essentially http://www.scimathmn.org/stemtc/sites/default/files/images/frameworks/math/6.4.1A/image008.jpg

Comment: Perhaps with `outer(1:ncol(df), 1:ncol(df), FUN= paste)` or may be using `dcast`, `spread` etc to reshape the dataset.  Without an example, it is hard to tell.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working unfortunately.

I'm attempting with d-cast. I'll update my original post to try and make it more  clear.

Comment: Updated comment with layout of original data. I wish to change it to a 6 x 6 grid to easily visualise the possible outcomes of a 2-dice throw.

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the input.  It is only a 14*2 input data.

Comment: `outer(1:6, 1:6, FUN= paste)` gets the expected output.  Here, the input data is not the one for the expected data.

Comment: Input data is incomplete, to post the data, do `dput(yourdata)` and copy and paste the result here

Comment: Unfortunately that output doesn't use existing data. What I wish to know is how to reorganise my original data, rather than create something new

Comment: Try `matrix(do.call(paste, df1), ncol=6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R alternative using `lapply` and `apply`

```
out =  do.call(rbind,
                lapply(split(data, data$d2),function(x) 
                apply(x, 1, function(y) paste(y['d2'], y['d1'], collapse = ' '))
               )
#>out                
#     1     2     3     4     5     6    
#1 "1 1" "1 2" "1 3" "1 4" "1 5" "1 6"
#2 "2 1" "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5" "2 6"
#3 "3 1" "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5" "3 6"
#4 "4 1" "4 2" "4 3" "4 4" "4 5" "4 6"
#5 "5 1" "5 2" "5 3" "5 4" "5 5" "5 6"
#6 "6 1" "6 2" "6 3" "6 4" "6 5" "6 6"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `paste` the columns and use `matrix` specifying the dimensions

```
matrix(do.call(paste, df1), ncol=6)
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6] 
#[1,] "1 1" "1 2" "1 3" "1 4" "1 5" "1 6"
#[2,] "2 1" "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5" "2 6"
#[3,] "3 1" "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5" "3 6"
#[4,] "4 1" "4 2" "4 3" "4 4" "4 5" "4 6"
#[5,] "5 1" "5 2" "5 3" "5 4" "5 5" "5 6"
#[6,] "6 1" "6 2" "6 3" "6 4" "6 5" "6 6"
```

If there are only two columns, we can also `paste` by subsetting the columns individually

```
matrix(paste(df1[,1], df1[,2]), ncol = 6)
```

If you need a `dcast/acast` approach, create another column by `paste`ing the columns of 'df1' and then do the `acast`.

```
library(reshape2)
acast(data.frame(df1, value=do.call(paste, df1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), ar~br)
#    1     2     3     4     5     6    
#1 "1 1" "1 2" "1 3" "1 4" "1 5" "1 6"
#2 "2 1" "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5" "2 6"
#3 "3 1" "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5" "3 6"
#4 "4 1" "4 2" "4 3" "4 4" "4 5" "4 6"
#5 "5 1" "5 2" "5 3" "5 4" "5 5" "5 6"
#6 "6 1" "6 2" "6 3" "6 4" "6 5" "6 6"
```

Or a similar option using `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(value= paste(ar, br)) %>%
   spread(br, value)
```

---

But, this can be created directly using `outer`

```
outer(1:6, 1:6, FUN= paste)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- expand.grid(ar=1:6, br=1:6)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Do you also know how to do it without specifying dimensions, such as a using cast function from reshape?

Comment: @user3200293  Updated with a `acast` approach from `reshape2`