# Reorganize/reshape data frame

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame of live trapping. There are two systems, each with different status. The week and the number of individuals in each status is given.

```
df <- data.frame (sys = rep(c("a","b"), each=3), 
              sta = rep(c("L","T","P"), times=2), 
              w01 = c("0","2","5","2","2","5"),
              w02 = c("3","2","2","4","6","1"),
              w03 = c("4","1","0","5","3","0"))
df
sys  sta  w01  w02  w03
a    L    0    3    4
a    T    2    2    1
a    P    5    2    0
b    L    2    4    5
b    T    2    6    3
b    P    5    1    0
```

I want a data frame showing for each number the system and status. The Result would look like this:

```
sys sta Num
a   L   0
a   L   3
a   L   4
a   T   2
a   T   2
a   T   1
a   P   5
a   P   2
a   P   0
b   L   2
b   L   4
b   L   5
b   T   2
b   T   6
b   T   3
b   P   5
b   P   1
b   P   0
```

I have absolutely no idea how doing this. I found this two questions/answers
[Reorganise 2x36 dataframe to a 6x6 dataframe. Dice throw visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271810/reorganise-2x36-dataframe-to-a-6x6-dataframe-dice-throw-visualisation)
[Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)
but cannot find a way to fit it for my problem.
Also i tried `reshape` but `direction = "wide"` does not give the output I need and I am sucked with the varying part of `direction = "long"`. Here is what I tried, but did not work...

```
a <- as.vector(colnames(df[-c(1,2)]))
df2 <- reshape(df, idvar = "sys", timevar = "sta", varying = a , direction = "long")
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this problem?
Thank you all and kind regards!

P.S.: I need the "new format" of my dataset for a friedman test (`friedman.test`). Will it work out in this way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format is exactly what you need, have you tried the other solutions there?

Comment: `df2 <- reshape(df, idvar = c("sys", "sta"),  varying = c('w01', 'w02', 'w03'), direction = "long", sep = '', new.row.names = 1:18)` gets you what you need. `reshape` is horrible, though; try to learn the `reshape2` or `tidyr` packages.

Comment: Thank you for finding a solution without additional packages!
If I need reorganizations like this more often, I will learn to use this packages. But if I just need it once, I am always happier with a solution, that does not require extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

It is part of the `tidyr` package, included in the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- gather(df, key = 'week', value = 'number', -sys, -sta)
```

The output:

```
   sys sta week number
1    a   L  w01      0
2    a   T  w01      2
3    a   P  w01      5
4    b   L  w01      2
5    b   T  w01      2
6    b   P  w01      5
7    a   L  w02      3
8    a   T  w02      2
9    a   P  w02      2
10   b   L  w02      4
11   b   T  w02      6
12   b   P  w02      1
13   a   L  w03      4
14   a   T  w03      1
15   a   P  w03      0
16   b   L  w03      5
17   b   T  w03      3
18   b   P  w03      0
```

---

How it works:

- `gather` takes all columns that are not excluded. Exclusion is handled by passing on `select` statements to the `...` argument. In this case, I am excluding `sys` and `sta`. As a result, the only column we are `gather`ing our values from is `all_w`.
- Furthermore we give gather a name for the `key` and a name for the `value` field. The key field will contain the column name that each element (row) of the output was taken from. The `value` will have the content of the row in that column.
- I would recommend to keep `week` as you might later on want to know the exposure time that generated one of your numbers. If not, you can drop it with `df %>% select(-week)`.
- You can undo this transformation doing `spread(out, key = week, value = number)`. Voila, your old `df`!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! This realy helps. I often fail in adapting code, because I have no idea what it is doing. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, my pleasure! I know `gather` and spread can be confusing at first. Just play around with it a little bit to get comfortable. Same for the other `tidyr` functions. And really do use the `tidyverse`, it's the best thing that has happened in R in a decade! You can get started here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    gather(key, value, -sys, -sta) %>% 
    select(-key) %>% 
    arrange(sys, sta)

#>    sys sta value
#> 1    a   L     0
#> 2    a   L     3
#> 3    a   L     4
#> 4    a   P     5
#> 5    a   P     2
#> 6    a   P     0
#> 7    a   T     2
#> 8    a   T     2
#> 9    a   T     1
#> 10   b   L     2
#> 11   b   L     4
#> 12   b   L     5
#> 13   b   P     5
#> 14   b   P     1
#> 15   b   P     0
#> 16   b   T     2
#> 17   b   T     6
#> 18   b   T     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Maybe there is a solution which doesn't require extra packages?

Comment: Haha, @GGamba, you beat me to it.
Leips, use dplyr or the tidyverse, it is worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` from `reshape2`

```
melt(df, id.vars = c("sys","sta"), value.name = "num")

#     sys sta variable num
# 1    a   L      w01   0
# 2    a   T      w01   2
# 3    a   P      w01   5
# 4    b   L      w01   2
# 5    b   T      w01   2
# 6    b   P      w01   5
# 7    a   L      w02   3
# 8    a   T      w02   2
# 9    a   P      w02   2
# 10   b   L      w02   4
# 11   b   T      w02   6
# 12   b   P      w02   1
# 13   a   L      w03   4
# 14   a   T      w03   1
# 15   a   P      w03   0
# 16   b   L      w03   5
# 17   b   T      w03   3
# 18   b   P      w03   0
```

If you want to remove the `variable` column use

`melt(df, id.vars = c("sys","sta"), value.name = "num")[,c(1,2,4)]`